# npm install error (EACCES) on secondary hard drive in EndeavourOS - Permission or Configuration Issue?

Tags: node.js, npm, permissions, drive

```
Error Message:
```

```
 (node:2906) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected...
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path /mnt/Munna/WEB/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
    npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied, access '/mnt/Munna/WEB/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild'
```

```
Steps Taken:
    Checked ownership and permissions of the directory and esbuild/bin/esbuild binary.
    Tried both local and global installations.
    Reviewed EndeavourOS documentation and forums for specific guidance.
Additional Information:
    Node.js version: 20.8.1
    npm version: (your version)
    Specific location of project on secondary drive: /mnt/Munna/WEB/my-vue-app
    Any other relevant system details or configurations.
```

Questions:

```
What could be causing the EACCES error in this specific scenario?
Are there additional permissions or configuration adjustments needed for installing npm packages on a secondary drive in EndeavourOS?
Are there any alternative approaches, like using n, that might help resolve this issue?
Has anyone else encountered a similar problem and found a solution?
```

I've already made some efforts to troubleshoot the issue, but I'm stuck and appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community.

Steps Taken:

```
Checked ownership and permissions of the directory and esbuild/bin/esbuild binary.
Tried both local and global installations.
Reviewed EndeavourOS documentation and forums for specific guidance.
```